# ASP.NET WebForms - Keeping contextual focus on Button controls

Tags: asp.net, events, client-side

Consider the following:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="b1" OnClick="b1_Click" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb2" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="b2" OnClick="b2_Click" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb3" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="b3" OnClick="b3_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Each TextBox has an associated Button. I want to be able to switch the focus on each of these Button controls, so that when I place my cursor in the 2nd textbox (`tb2`) and press Enter, the associated button (`b2`) gets clicked and the associated `OnClick` event gets fired.

I've got a few ideas myself, but I'd like you guys' feedback/lessons-learned before I start potentially wasting time on implementing a broken solution.

**NOTE:**

- Using the HTML fieldset element is not an option--Some of the interfaces are very complex.
- There can be multiple inputs associated with one button.

Comment: Are you using a particular JavaScript library, or do you want a vanilla approach?

Comment: A jQuery approach will do just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could trap the keydown event on the Textbox and then fire the button's callback javascript if it's the enter key. You can get the callback reference using [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx)

Alternatively you could wrap every textbox in it's own Panel, which exposes a [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property.

Comment: Didn't know you could set the DefaultButton on a Panel, nice answer

Comment: +1 for DefaultButton. Just don't set the GroupingText, otherwise you'll end up with a <fieldset> and not a <div>

Comment: Setting the DefaultButton property is sort of the same thing as using a fieldset. Which I can't implement due to the complexity of the interfaces. I had __doPostback() in mind as well. Perhaps extending a Button control and implementing a property which I can then pick up onsubmit. Hmm :)

Comment: <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton=""> did the trick. Thanks Pike65.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do a nice simple route using jQuery if you are using it.

Simply doing the following might work nicely:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function(){    
     jQuery('input').keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        jQuery(this).next().trigger('click');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And then code side you would have the relevant event handler triggered, or just simply see which button was clicked by querying the sender object id

Comment: Looks good. But what if you are writing in a textfield element? :)

Comment: Aye, but then you'd fire the click-event on a button, when you want to do a line-break in a textarea :)

Comment: Touché! Though this would also be a problem then in any solution that was used! :)